# Scatterplot in R with varied length numerical variables

Tags: r, statistics, data-visualization

How do I plot a scatterplot of two numerical vector in R using "plot( )" function, if  both the vectors are very large (say 1000 variables each) and one vector is having several NA values ?

Answer (score 0):

You should have no problem with this, R will handle the `NA`s by not plotting them:

```
set.seed(1)
x <- 1:100
y <- 1:100
x[sample(1:length(x), 40)] <- NA
y[sample(1:length(y), 40)] <- NA
plot(x, y)
```

[image]

Or if you're dying for some representation of the `NA`s, why not plot them on the axis with some sort of alternate `pch` so you can reference in the legend:

```
plot(x, y, ylim = c(min(y[!is.na(y)]) - 1, max(y[!is.na(y)]) + 1), xlim = c(min(x[!is.na(x)]) - 1, max(x[!is.na(x)]) + 1))
y.for.x.na <- y[is.na(x)]
y.for.x.na <- y.for.x.na[!is.na(y.for.x.na)]

x.for.y.na <- x[is.na(y)]
x.for.y.na <- x.for.y.na[!is.na(x.for.y.na)]

points(rep(min(x[!is.na(x)]) - 1, length(y.for.x.na)), y.for.x.na, col = "red", pch = 4)
points(x.for.y.na, rep(min(y[!is.na(y)]) - 1, length(x.for.y.na)), col = "red", pch = 4)
```

[image]

If you encounter a situation where x and y are both `NA` then its really up to you what to do!

Comment: I was having two dataset, one was time series with no NA value, another has many NA value. plot( ) function needs two vectors of similar size. I was able to do so by omiting rows with NA value using na.omit( ) function. And after this it was just like normal two numerical vectors as argument to    plot(  ) function.

Comment: So what do you actually want? Please be more specific in your post and provide some sample data using `dput`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it was helpful. I am new to programming and to 'R'. I will try to be more accurate.

Comment: @VivekKhetan do you need more from this answer? Please accept if it meets your needs

Comment: No, i don't need more on it. Thanks